# IE (Z-index rendering problem)

Tags: asp.net, css, cross-browser

I have an ASP.NET application that renders a 3rd party (Telerik's) menu control *under* 
another control (RadDock) when the menu expands.

This artifact ONLY happens in IE7. Not in Safari/FF/Opera/Chrome (Have I left any out?)

The menu control needs to be rendered OVER the other control.

I have Google'd this a fair amount, but have yet to find a simple solution to fix it for IE7.

What is the easiest to solve this problem for IE?

Also do you know if this z-index problem has been resolved in the (pending?) IE8?

This Q is not meant to start a browser flame war. Please only respond if you have a
relevant comment.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: This most likely isn't directly related to Telerik's controls. Can you be specific about which html elements are overlapping?

Comment: I wanna see the answer too. In our project our menu overlapped by content too, but only in the places where I use TabControl

Comment: tvanfosson got me on the right track...
My master page: <div id=container><div id=content><div id=side> menu control </div></div></div>
I had to specify same z-index for 3 div's as well as for menu control in the CSS.

Comment: FYI, Telerik default z-indexes:
 
RadAjaxLoadingPanel - 90000
RadToolBar - 9000
RadToolTip - 8000
RadMenu - 7000
RadCombo - 6000
RadDatePicker - 5000
RadColorPicker - 4000
RadWindow - 3000
RadGrid's PopUp edit form - 2500
RadSplitter - 2000
RadDock - 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is similar or not, but I had an issue with z-indexing where when the z-index was applied to the elements of a container, but not to the container itself, the z-index wasn't being properly applied to the child elements.  This manifested itself as background borders appearing over the top of the menu items that should have been on top.  I solved the issue by applying the same z-index to the container holding the menu items.  I don't know how the Telerik controls set up their CSS, but you may want to check that the class being assigned to the container has an appropriate z-index as well as the menu items themselves.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks! I had to explicitly specify a z-index for ALL 'parent' elements (3:container/content/side) of the menu control in CSS as well as for the menu control! <div id=container><div id=content><div id=side> menu control </div></div></div>

Nice one ;P

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problems like that before, although not with the 3rd party controls you mentioned. Check to see if either of the controls sets it's own z-index conditionally if the browser is IE. If that's not the case, try setting a specific z-index for each of the controls (or their containers) to make sure IE doesn't fall back to some sort of default unknown z-index.

If the z-index changes do not fix it, it may actually be a positioning problem rather than a z-index problem. Positioning problems are quite common (from my own experience) when you try to do cross-browser compatibility.